# How can I display an element only if user is logged in?

Tags: php

I am trying to display a div  only if the user is logged in, therefore only if `$_SESSION['MM_Username']` exists and is equal to something so to achieve this I came up with the following code. The session variables are set and I know they exist however when I log out I still see the div:

```
<ul id="example-1" class="sticklr" style="list-style:none;display:<?php if ($_SESSION['MM_Username']=='' & $_SESSION['MM_Username']==NULL){echo('none');}?>">
```

How can I debug this to see whats the problem, or if someone knows a better way to display a div only if user is logged in please let me know .

Comment: Firstly, why are you using & instead of || ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if a variable is set in PHP you can use the `isset()` function:

```
<?php

//this checks to see if the variable isset and not null, if it is not set or is null then echo 'none';
if (!isset($_SESSION['MM_Username']) || empty($_SESSION['MM_Username'])){
    echo 'none';
}

?>
```

`empty()` checks if there is a value associated with the variable: http://php.net/empty

> If a variable has been unset with unset(), it will no longer be set.
>   isset() will return FALSE if testing a variable that has been set to
>   NULL. Also note that a NULL byte ("\0") is not equivalent to the PHP
>   NULL constant.

*Source: http://php.net/isset*

One cool thing about `isset()` is that it won't throw an error or warning message when you ask if a variable is set that is not.

Answer (score 1):

Set your test condition to a variable at the beginning of your script:

`$isLoggedIn = isset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);`

then just wrap your markup in an if:

```
<?php if (isLoggedIn) { ?>
<ul></ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `var isLoggedIn` isn't Javascript ?!

Comment: @Márcio haha, oops! Fixed for PHP syntax.

Comment: this works as well for my requirements, thanks,  i think this is the same as the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Several issues: 
1. You should use the || (OR) operator for the if statement (this is probably the root of the problem, as this if statement will always return false... something cannot be both an empty string and null)
2. If this block contains any kind of secure information you should remove it altogether rather than just hiding it with css

Comment: thanks for the advice it dosent contain sensitive info but is good to keep in mind that i shouldn't hide sensitive information with css

Answer (score 1):

Register a session  with Boolean value 'True' after user login is success.

Ex: $_SESSION['userLogin']=TRUE;

You can display your element as bellow,

```
    <ul id="example-1" class="sticklr" style="<?php if($_SESSION['userLogin']) echo 'display:block;'; else 'display:none;'?>">
```

Assign FALSE value to that session when that user logged out

$_SESSION['userLogin']=FALSE;

Comment: iam sorry iam a noob so i don't really understand where to set $_SESSION['userLogin'], on the same page or on the login page ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `session_destroy` or `unset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])` on logout ?

I think this can helps you.

Comment: i use session destroy , but i dont think that is the issue , thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this in different way.  I would only display the `<ul>` **if** the session variable is not null.  Something like this perhaps:

```
<?php if( !is_null($_SESSION['MM_Username']) ): ?>
<ul id="example-1" class="sticklr" style="list-style:none;">
  <!-- ... -->
</ul>
<?php endif ?>
```